# Session get destroyed after a certain time

Tags: java, session

After a certain time and if I do nothing on the web page, I get this error :

> java.lang.illegalstateexception forward not allowed response is
>   already committed

I think that it's because the session is destroyed, what can I do to redirect the user to the login page if the session is destroyed. Or is there another way to resolve this error?

Comment: _Forward not allowed response is already committed_. You have already done a redirect and then try to output some more data to the output stream.

Comment: What web application framework are you using? The simplest solution would be to develop a filter to validate session and do the redirect.

Comment: @Satya So what should I do ? Because if I wait like 5 or 10 min and doing nothing on the page and then refresh, I get this error

Comment: Post your code then only others will help you.@SimonM.

Comment: @Satya The thing is that I don't know the code to post because I don't really know where the error come from

Comment: So try to debug your code it will helps you.